# C++ OpenGL: undefined reference to 'glutSwapBuffers'

Tags: c++, opengl

I am new to C++ and trying to create a window with OpenGL. My program gives the error `undefined reference to 'glutSwapBuffers'`. I did not understand why is it giving this error for hours but I just looked and saw that the `glutSwapBuffers` function is defined like this in my header file:

`extern void APIENTRY glutSwapBuffers(void);`

I edited the header and changed it to an example function and the function worked. I searched for `GLUT` and downloaded the header files that I found. Definition was always same.

I understood why does not my code work but I do not know why the `glutSwapBuffers` is defined like this. Do I need to include other libraries?

Comment: An undefined reference error is a LINKER error. You have supplied the header with the definition, but the linker isn't able to find the implementation (which is in a lib/dll).

Comment: Do I need to link the `.lib` files in lib directory that I downloaded?

Comment: Probably. Depends on the compiler used and on the lib you downloaded.

Comment: There are a lot of library. Which one do I need to link and how will I link? I am using MinGW.